# What does "del sys.modules[module]" actually do?

Tags: python, module, sys, python-internals

As everyone knows, you can do `del sys.modules[module]` to delete an imported module. So I was thinking: how is this different from rewriting `sys.modules`? An interesting fact is, rewriting `sys.modules` can't truely delete a module.

```
# a_module.py
print("a module imported")
```

Then

```
import sys

def func1():
    import a_module
    # del sys.modules['a_module']
    sys.modules = {
        k: v for k, v in sys.modules.items() if 'a_module' not in k}
    print('a_module' not in sys.modules)  # True

def func2():
    import a_module

func1()  # a module imported
func2()  # no output here
```

If I use `del sys.modules['a_module']`, calling `func2()` also prints `a module imported`, which implies that `a_module` is successfully deleted.

My question is: What does `del sys.modules[module]` actually do, besides changing the dictionary?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sys.modules` is the *Python-accessible reference* to the *canonical* data structure for tracking what modules are imported. Removing a name from that dictionary means that any future attempts to import the module will result in Python loading the module from scratch.

In other words, whenever you use an `import` statement, the first thing Python does is check if the dictionary that `sys.modules` references already has an entry for that module and proceed with the next step (binding names in the current namespace) without loading the module first. If you delete entries from `sys.modules`, then Python won't find the already-loaded module and loads again.

Note the careful wording about *Python-accessible* here. The actual dictionary lives on the Python heap and `sys.modules` is just one reference to it. You *replaced* that reference with another dictionary by assigning to `sys.modules`. However, the interpreter has *more references to it*; they just are not accessible from Python code, not without `ctypes` trickery to access the C-API anyway.

Note that this is [*explicitly documented*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

> However, replacing the dictionary will not necessarily work as expected and deleting essential items from the dictionary may cause Python to fail.

From the C-API, you'd have to use `PyThreadState_Get()->interp->modules` to get the internal reference to the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. Is this documented somewhere? I didn't know there are "more refs".

Comment: @laike9m: a lot of this is implementation detail; I did a quick deep-dive in the source code. Other Python implementations are likely to handle interpreter state differently.

Comment: @laike9m: I note, for example, that the [C-API documentation for `PyInterpreterState`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyInterpreterState) makes no mention of any struct members, and the documentation for `sys.modules` explicitly warns against replacing the `sys.modules` reference.

Comment: What good does it do for the C-API to have separate references? The "obvious"/natural way for it to work would be for modules to be ref counted like everything else, so if you did `del sys.modules[module_name]` it would be completely unloaded as long as no other objects held references to it.

Comment: Also possibly worth drawing a distinction between `del sys.modules[foo]` and reassigning `sys.modules` to a different dictionary instance -- the latter seems more likely to cause problems with references on the C side to me, but this is based on how I imagine it should work, not real reading of the sources.