# undo "import math" in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

After I import a module in python, how could I undo the effect in the same python work space?

For example, after I typed "import random" in a python IDLE, I want to remove all the imported functions in the module "random" in the same workspace, how could I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unimport a python module which is already imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234156/how-to-unimport-a-python-module-which-is-already-imported)

Comment: Unfortunately no real way to "unimport", you can delete the reference to it.

Comment: why would you want to?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to wrap the import and the code using that import in a specific scope. That way once the scope exits, the imported library won't be in reach.

```
def do_something_with_random():
    import random
    print("do something interesting with random", random.choice([0, 1]))

print("perform task that don't need random")
do_something_with_random()
print("function call uses random, but doesn't add it to your globals")
print("continue performing tasks that don't need random")
```