# PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_remotedata

Tags: python, python-import, pytest

I created some unit tests and run them from the same file.  For tests in the same file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pytest
    pytest.main(['--tb=short', __file__])
```

For tests in another file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pytest
    pytest.main(['./test_stuff.py', "--capture=sys"])
```

In either case, when I execute the file the first time, it works fine, but the second and subsequent times it gives a bunch of warnings:

```
============================== warnings summary ===============================
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:754
  C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:754: PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_remotedata
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)
  C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:754: PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_openfiles
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)
  C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:754: PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_doctestplus
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)
  C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:754: PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten: pytest_arraydiff
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
==================== 1 passed, 4 warnings in 0.06 seconds
```

Is there any way to make these warnings go away?

Restarting the kernel works, but IPython's `%reset` and `%clear` aren't enough to fix it, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `subprocess` instead of `pytest.main`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(['pytest', '--tb=short', str(__file__)])
```

If the above does not print anything, try the workaround (as suggested in comments):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    with Popen(['pytest',
                '--tb=short',  # shorter traceback format
                str(__file__)], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
                universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: This doesn't print the output at all, though...  :/

Comment: It does. :) At least in Spyder IDE with ipython console (Python 3.7). Also direct call from command line and repeated calls from inside ipython do print anything you like... Maybe you catch somewhere else your sdtout and stderr?

Comment: No it doesn't print anything in Spyder.  This works though: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3143#issuecomment-464973797

Comment: Upvoting because your answer led me to find the other, but it would be best if yours was edited to do something similar.

Comment: It is strange actually that my Spyder (version 3.3.3) catches and prints everything without any workarounds and yours does not. What is your spyder/python/ipython versions configuration?

Comment: Spyder 3.3.3,  Python 3.7.1, IPython 7.2.0, pytest 4.0.2

Comment: Well, my configuration differs only in pytest. I have version 4.2.0. Neverthless i edited the answer to cover the no printing case.

Comment: I just tested things on Windows and subprocessed pytest really does not print output. It seems this is Windows specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that pytest just isn't really designed to perform `pytest.main()` calls repeatedly from within the same process. The [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code) mentions:

> Calling pytest.main() will result in importing your tests and any
>   modules that they import. Due to the caching mechanism of python’s
>   import system, making subsequent calls to pytest.main() from the same
>   process will not reflect changes to those files between the calls. For
>   this reason, making multiple calls to pytest.main() from the same
>   process (in order to re-run tests, for example) is not recommended.

So actually the real danger of performing multiple `pytest.main()` calls within the same process is that you could get false-positive or false-negative test results if you've edited your code files inbetween.

The [Spyder IDE](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) has a nifty feature though that seems to negate this issue: the [User Module Reloader (UMR)](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#using-umr-to-reload-changed-modules). If enabled, then any changed user modules are automatically reloaded when a script file is (re-)run.

Therefore I think that as long as you're working in Spyder (with the UMR feature enabled!), you can safely rerun `pytest.main()` without the need for a new console. The pytest module already-imported warnings you can then simply suppress, since those pytest modules will not have changed. This can be done with pytest's [`-W` flag](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#warnings-capture). Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pytest
    pytest.main(['./test_stuff.py', "--capture=sys", "-W", "ignore:Module already imported:pytest.PytestWarning"])
```

Comment: It didn't used to have this problem. Is there a recommended way to run tests every time a file is edited and run?

Comment: The recommended way seems to be to always use a new process for every pytest run (see [github issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3143)).

Comment: @endolith My own recommendation would be to use to an [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) that supports custom run configurations. Within the IDE set up a dedicated run configuration for your pytest tests (one that always launches a new process).

Comment: I'm using Spyder, and when I configured it for "Execute in dedicated console" or "Remove all variables before execution", it doesn't help.

Comment: @endolith "Execute in dedicated console" results in a new console (i.e. new process) being started upon first run of the code file, but not upon subsequent reruns of the same code file. "Remove all variables" results in only user-defined variables being removed. Try using the run configuration options as described in the edited answer instead.

Comment: That works, but ugh, that's a plain Python terminal that doesn't even support tab completion, let alone variable explorer, etc.  :(  This used to work fine, I just had tests running from my script, and every time I edit it, I Run it and it says whether the tests still pass.  Maybe I should look into a different test package?

Comment: @endolith "evert time I edit it, I Run it and it says whether the tests still pass." This surprised me at first. I was expecting that subsequent test runs would be giving false-positive or false-negative results (due to edited code files not being reloaded). However after discovering and reading about [Spyder's User Module Reloader (UMR)](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#using-umr-to-reload-changed-modules) it's starting to make sense. This UMR ensures that previously imported user modules are automatically reloaded if they've been changed (quite a useful feature).

Comment: @endolith I think this means that as long as you're working in Spyder, you can actually safely rerun `pytest.main()` without the need for a new console. The warnings that you were getting you can simply suppress (see edited answer).

Comment: That sounds promising, but I still get the warnings when I use your suppression switch.  The `--disable-warnings` option in @SilentGuy's answer works though.

Comment: @endolith Hmm, I think the warnings filter is not working as it should due to a [bug in pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4439). Regarding the [`--disable-warnings`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#disabling-warnings-summary) option: do keep in mind that this will also suppress any and all warnings generated by your own code files.

Comment: The -W option in very useful: `"-W", "ignore::pytest.PytestAssertRewriteWarning"`

Answer (score 4):

If you are only concerned about warnings, you can use `--disable-warnings` argument. You can also filter out only the warnings you are getting now with `--pythonwarnings=PYTHONWARNINGS` argument in pytest.main . `pytest --help` has more info about these arguments.

It seems that you are invoking pytest with ipython or jupyter. python.main imports pytest specific modules at the time of pytest initialization. When you run pytest.main again, it throws the warnings. There are two possible ways to reload pytest to avoid getting this initialization warnings.

You can either use [pytest.exit](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-exit) after pytest.main or [reload pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234156/how-to-unimport-a-python-module-which-is-already-imported) after pytest.main .

Let us know if these approaches work.

Comment: Be careful. While these solutions will indeed get rid of the pytest warnings, one larger issue remains: the user's to-be-tested code files are not reloaded each time, so any changes made to the code files are ignored during subsequent pytest runs.

Comment: `--disable-warnings` works, but `--pythonwarnings=PYTHONWARNINGS` says `INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\warnings.py", line 236, in _getaction
INTERNALERROR>     raise _OptionError("invalid action: %r" % (action,))
INTERNALERROR> warnings._OptionError: invalid action: 'PYTHONWARNINGS'`

Comment: Correct syntax to hide particular warning in this case (taken from an answer here): pytest.main(['./test_stuff.py', "--capture=sys", "--pythonwarnings", "ignore:Module already imported:pytest.PytestWarning"])

You should look into reloading pytest module as that will be the cleanest solution in your case.