pytest equivalent of unittest.main()
I can run in debug mode a unit test test_foo.py by simplying pressing F5 in my IDE of choice:
# test_foo_module.py
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I'd have thought the pytest exact equivalent to be:
# test_foo_module.py
import pytest

def test_foo():
    assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()

But pytest.main() scans the whole project directory. I want to execute only this module in debug mode.

pytest.main optionally takes pytest CLI arguments (args) as its first argument (if not specified, it defaults to sys.argv). So, giving the current file name via args should do it,
# test_foo_module.py
import pytest

def test_foo():
    assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__])


If your modules import other pytest modules, you may run into "PytestWarning: Module already imported so cannot be rewritten" unless you use subprocess.call instead of pytest.main as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54666289/7058266:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(['pytest', '--tb=short', str(__file__)])

And to expand on an earlier answer, you can also include pytest command-line args in your pytest.main call, such as -s to see the output of print(), Eg:
import pytest

def test_print():
    print("Can you see this?")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])

