# Replacing a class from external module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to replace a whole class [`Instruction`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/instruction.py#L49) from an [external module](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra) with my own implementation `NamedRoutine`. I want the external module to use **my** re-definition instead of the original class `Instruction`.

In order to have the best compatibility possible, and because I don't want to re-type the `Instruction` class, the redefined class inherits from `Instruction`. The `NamedRoutine` implementation is:

```
from qiskit.circuit.instruction import Instruction

from ._interfaces import interfaces


class NamedRoutine(Instruction, interfaces.NamedRoutine):
    def __init__(self, name: str, num_qubits: int, num_clbits: int, params):
        super().__init__(
            name=name, num_qubits=num_qubits, num_clbits=num_clbits, params=params
        )
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def from_Routine(rout: Instruction) -> "NamedRoutine":
        named_routine = NamedRoutine(
            rout.name, rout.num_qubits, rout.num_clbits, rout.params
        )
        named_routine.definition = rout.definition
        return named_routine

    @staticmethod
    def from_Routine_and_name(rout: Instruction, name: str) -> "NamedRoutine":
        named_routine = NamedRoutine(
            name, rout.num_qubits, rout.num_clbits, rout.params
        )
        named_routine.definition = rout.definition
        return named_routine

    def inverse(self) -> "NamedRoutine":
        return NamedRoutine.from_Routine_and_name(
            super().inverse(), name="D-" + self.name
        )
```

As you can see, there is no compatibility issue between the 2 classes. The `NamedRoutine` implementation just ensure that a proper name is set, adds 2 static methods and overloads one method of `Instruction` to change the instance `name` attribute accordingly.

In order to replace completely the definition of `qiskit.circuit.instruction.Instruction` by my `NamedRoutine` implementation, I tried to call the following function before any `qiskit`-related code is imported:

```
def _wrap_instruction_class():
    import qiskit.circuit.instruction
    from .NamedRoutine import NamedRoutine

    setattr(qiskit.circuit.instruction, "Instruction", NamedRoutine)
    setattr(qiskit.circuit, "Instruction", NamedRoutine)
```

Note: `Instruction` is imported in the `__init__.py` file of `qiskit.circuit`.

This method **nearly** works as I am successfully replacing the definitions of `Instruction` by my own implementation.

The problem I am still facing is the following: when importing `qiskit.circuit.instruction`, the `__init__.py` files of the [`qiskit`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/__init__.py) and [`qiskit.circuit`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/__init__.py) modules are executed, and load a ton of methods/classes with the original definition of the `Instruction` method (as it is still not replaced).

The number of methods/functions/classes using this `Instruction` class being quite huge, I don't want to track them one by one. Moreover, this solution would require me to check after each update of the `qiskit` library if one more routine/function/class need to be "injected".

I also searched for a solution "unimporting" everything from the `qiskit` library except the `Instruction` class, and then re-importing all the relevant parts once the `Instruction` class has been modified, but it appears that [unimporting is not possible in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234156/how-to-unimport-a-python-module-which-is-already-imported).

One possible solution would be to recursively import all the packages/modules of the `qiskit` library and replace the symbol `Instruction` with my definition if it is defined in the module, but this would require to import **all** the modules from `qiskit`. My software is not really constrained by runtime, but this takes approximately 4 seconds on my laptop with a recent SSD and a rather clean (low number of packages) virtual environment, and it may take a lot more depending on the packages installed on the machine.

Do any of you have another solution, possibly more efficient than iterating over all the modules to find the modules in qiskit where the `Instruction` symbol is defined and replace it?

Comment: Why don't you just change the `qiskit.circuit.instruction` files directly?

Comment: I want the modification to be non-persistent. I don't want the users to have to re-install each time they need to use the library without my tool. If there is a secure way to roll-back the modifications done to the file when the Python interpreter exits, then this idea may suits my needs.

Comment: I just found the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html) library. It is may suits my needs but I already see some issues: a program running in parallel will be affected by the modifications and performing IOs at program termination seems strange to me. But it may work!