# Import a Python module without adding it to the local namespace

Tags: python, python-import

## What I'd like to do

I'd like to import a Python module without adding it to the local namespace.

In other words, I'd like to do this:

```
import foo
del foo
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

## Why I want to do it

The short version is that importing `foo` has a side effect that I want, but I don't really want it in my namespace afterwards.

The long version is that I have a base class that uses [`__init_subclass__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) to register its subclasses. So `base.py` looks like this:

```
class Base:
    _subclasses = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls._subclasses[cls.__name__] = cls

    @classmethod
    def get_subclass(cls, class_name):
        return cls._subclasses[class_name]
```

And its subclasses are defined in separate files, e.g. `foo_a.py`:

```
from base import Base

class FooA(Base):
    pass
```

and so on.

The net effect here is that if I do

```
from base import Base

print(f"Before import: {Base._subclasses}")

import foo_a
import foo_b

print(f"After import: {Base._subclasses}")
```

then I would see

```
Before import: {}
After import: {'FooA': <class 'foo_a.FooA'>, 'FooB': <class 'foo_b.FooB'>}
```

So I needed to import these modules for the side effect of adding a reference to `Base._subclasses`, but now that that's done, I don't need them in my namespace anymore because I'm just going to be using `Base.get_subclass()`.

I know I could just leave them there, but this is going into an `__init__.py` so I'd like to tidy up that namespace.

`del` works perfectly fine, I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner or more idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unimport a python module which is already imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234156/how-to-unimport-a-python-module-which-is-already-imported)

Comment: @jezza_99 I don't see how that answers this question. The OP is asking how to perform an import without assigning a module object to a variable. That question is about unloading/reloading an imported module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import a module without assigning the module object to a variable, you can use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and ignore the return value:

```
import importlib

importlib.import_module("foo")
```

Note that using `importlib.import_module` is preferable over using the `__import__` builtin directly for simple usages. See the [builtin documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__) for details.