# Avoid adding file and folder names to a module's namespace

Tags: python, import, module, subdirectory

Is there a way to avoid adding file and folder names to a module's namespace? With the following structure:

```
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── folder
│   │   └── func2.py
│   └── func1.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .func1 import a
from .folder.func2 import b
```

Then importing

```
>>> import pkg
>>> dir(pkg)

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__',
'__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'a', 'b', 'folder', 'func1']
```

Is there a way to set up the project so `folder` and `func1` don't appear in the module's namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your `__init__.py` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/32234323/16173463:

```
del folder
del func1
```

Result:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> dir(pkg)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'a', 'b']
```